# Exporting collection from a Azure MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

So I have a MongoDB in an Azure Cosmos DB service. It contains a collection of 1500 documents and I want to download this whole collection in a JSON format. I've tried several methods without success, namely

```
test_collection.find({})
```

Which gave me a cursor timeout. Using

```
{ timeout : false }
```

Did not help. Then I tried to use mongoexport:

```
mongoexport -h host_name --port 1234 -u user_name -p password 
-d admin -c collection_name -o data.json --ssl
```

which gives me 0 exported records. The firewall IP access control is off and I can connect to the database through Mongo shell just fine. Trying to export other collections doesn't work either. Also, it has to be by ssl otherwise I get a "database not found" right away.

I've thought about using skip and limit but it doesn't seem to be a good idea with large (and expanding) collections? Could someone please give me some advise as to how I best achieve or overcome these obstacles to download my collection? It doesn't matter how, I just simply need to download the collection. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You possibly have a few incorrect parameters, and a missing parameter:

- Are you sure your database name is `admin`?
- You need to specify --tlsInsecure
- For host/port: this should look something like:

  `/h yourcosmosaccount.documents.azure.com:10255`

If you take a look at the "quick start" tab in your Cosmos DB settings, you'll see the command line string for `mongo` (well, `mongo.exe` in the example). Just grab those parameters and use them for `mongoexport`.

I just ran this against a sample Cosmos DB (MongoDB API) database of mine, with no issue:

[image: mongoexport image]

Here's the generic command-line equivalent:

```bash
mongoexport /h <host:port> /u <username> /p <password> /ssl /tlsInsecure /d <database> /c <collection> /o <outputfile>.json
```

Comment: Thank you! The -sslAllowInvalidCertificates helped.

Comment: can you post the complete query here please!

Comment: @Kitwradr - there's no query here. This question was about using `mongoexport` - the OP had missing parameters. I explained this. And I showed everything needed to run `mongoexport` (which solved the OP's issue). If you have additional questions not covered here, please post a new question.

Comment: @Kitwradr there you go quick fix `
mongoexport /h <host_name:post> /u <user_name> /p <password> /d <db_name> /c <collection_name> /ssl /sslAllowInvalidCertificates /o <dir location/data.json>`

Comment: @DavidMakogon thanks your solution helped but was no way to get command line statement from image you attached that's why I have added seperate ans to make others life easier

Comment: @monikapatelIT - Ah, so this is about posting formatted text vs a graphic image - that is not clear from the comment posted back in 2018. Easy enough to remedy: I just edited my original answer to include a formatted-text version. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
mongoexport /uri "mongodb+srv://user:password@endpoint.cosmos.azure.com/?tls=true&authMechanism=SCRAM-SHA-256&retrywrites=false&maxIdleTimeMS=120000" /d dbname /c inputs /o inputs.json
```